# Retornar consulta WebSQL em uma variavel global?

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-cordova, phonegap-buillder

Não estou  conseguindo retornar os valores referente a consulta SQl
Apenas dentro da função

```
$(function () {

var sincronizado = 'no';
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM quilometragem WHERE veiculo=?', [id], function (tx, resultado) {                  
        var rows = resultado.rows[0];
        //Aqui retorna o ID da consulta
        alert(rows.id);
        console.log(rows.id);                
    });

        //Aqui não retorna o ID da consulta
        alert(rows.id);
        console.log(rows.id);

}, null);
       //Aqui não retorna o ID da consulta
        alert(rows.id);
        console.log(rows.id);
});
```

Preciso retornar a variavel rows em outra function, para mandar via
ajax para o servidor PHP e aramazenar no mysql.

Busco os dados WebSQL banco de dados Local e mando via ajax para mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Seja bem-vindo ao StackOverflow, bom vamos lá no trecho onde você diz:

> Preciso retornar a variavel rows em outra function, para mandar via
>   ajax para o servidor PHP e aramazenar no mysql.

você mesmo já respondeu sua pergunta, se você já tem o resultado da query e já tem uma função que processa esse dado basta chamar essa função passando o resultado como argumento.

Veja o código abaixo:

```js
function funcao_que_faz_ajax (rows) {
      alert("função que faz ajax chamada.\nVeja o console para mais detalhes.");
      console.log(rows);
}

db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM quilometragem WHERE veiculo=?', [car], function (tx, resultado) {                  
        funcao_que_faz_ajax(resultado.rows);
    });
}, null);
```

Se você quiser seguir o padrão de callbacks que o websql utiliza você pode englobar a parte que faz acesso ao banco dentro de uma função que recebe um callback e você quando precisar basta chamar a função passando a outra função como argumento. Na prática é bem simples veja:

```js
function selectCarById(db, id, callback) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM quilometragem WHERE veiculo=?', [id], function (tx, resultado) {                  
            if(callback) callback(resultado)                     
        });
    }, null);
}
```

E a chamada dessa função seria:

```js
selectCarById(db, 1, function (resultado) {
    // resultado obtido
    alert("Resultado obtido\nVide console para mais detalhes");
    console.log(resultado.rows);
    // To do.. enviar via ajax 
});
```

Como você está usando jQuery você pode ainda usar todo o poder dos [eventos personalizados](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) e reagir a determinados eventos em seu documento e criar um código mais desacoplado ainda. Veja:

```js
$(document).on('veiculos.find', function (event, veiculos) {
    alert("Veículos Recebido.\nVeja o console para mais detalhes");
    console.log(veiculos);
    // To do.. enviar via ajax 
});

db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM quilometragem WHERE veiculo=?', [id], function (tx, resultado) {                  
        $(document).trigger('veiculos.find', resultado.rows);                 
    });
}, null);
```

Qual dessas 3 formas você deve usar?

Bom eu particularmente gosto dos eventos, pois seu código fica totalmente desacoplado e futuramente caso você precise fazer mais alguma com o resultado da query basta escutar o evento novamente e seguir com a lógica e você não precisará mexer em código que já está funcionando.

Dessa forma seu código fica "Aberto para inclusão e fechado para edição", mas é aquela coisa né.... Você decide, veja com qual das formas seu código melhor se adapta.

Espero ter te ajudado.